# jquery page javascript not loading on ajax div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[REVISED]

Hi, thanks for the feedback guys. I revised by question btw.
To make things clearer here's my html page (sample only)

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
     <form>
     <div class="loadAjax"></div>
     <div class="toggle">[form inputs here]</toggle>
     <a href="#" class="btn">Submit</a>
     </form>
     <script>[several js scripts here]</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my main js file:

```
$(function() {
     [some lines here]
     $('.toggle').toggle();
     $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
               url: 'http://example.com/ajaxpage',
               type: 'POST',
               data: $('form').serialize(),
               beforeSend: function() {
                     ...
               },
               success: function(data) {
                     $.getScript('js/main.js');
                     $('.content').html(data);
               }
          });
     });
});
```

The page that will be loaded in div.loadAjax.

```
<div class="toggle">ajax page load</div>
```

Taking this as an example, the toggle on the main page seems to work. But the `div.toggle` on the `div.loadAjax` doesn't. I need to set the `$.getScipt()` in order to reload the main.js file again. Shouldn't the `div.loadAjax` inherit the main.js since it is loaded already in the first place? Why do I still need to reload it again using the `$.getScript()`?

NOTE: I'm using ajax to do a form post on a PHP page.

Thanks again!

Comment: $('.content').empty().html(data) ?

Comment: Im sorry, i dont fully get it. you want to be able to fetch script and just print the Data result from ajax into specific div? i just want to be sure

Comment: where you have loaded the script?? in the ajax loading url or in the main file to where the data gets loaded??

Comment: @user1781041 Wait, what you mean is that all listeners like Click and stuff like that are not working?

Comment: Show us more of your code. Probably there's just a problem with event handling of dynamical added elements...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I revised my question though.

Comment: You have an error in your markup `</toggle>` is wrong it should be `</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for toggle was already executed on your first page load. That will not execute again automatically without a page reload, otherwise you have to trigger it again or should load  your script again as you did now.

Try attaching it to click event and trigger it dynamically using `.trigger`

```
$(function() {
     [some lines here]

     $(".toggle").on("click", function(){
                           $('.toggle').toggle();
                             });

    $('.toggle').trigger("click");

     $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
               url: 'http://example.com/ajaxpage',
               type: 'POST',
               data: $('form').serialize(),
               beforeSend: function() {
                     ...
               },
               success: function(data) {

                     $('.content').html(data);
                     $('.toggle').trigger("click");
               }
          });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `$.load()` method: http://api.jquery.com/load/

This will let you perform an Ajax call, inject the results back onto the DOM of your page and also supports executing scripts loaded via the request.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I revised my question though.